# Why do -moz-transform and -webkit-transform not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to move an element down the page with `translateY()`. I know that `-webkit` is used for Chrome and `-moz` is used for Firefox. I'm trying to use them to remedy the problem of `translateY()`. The issue is, if I use `translateY(-53%)` to move the element down on Chrome, it works fine. If I use the same code on Firefox, the element is too far up on the page. Any help? I've tried switching the two, removing one or the other, and nothing worked.

If someone has any other way to fix the `translateY()` issue not working across browsers, I'll be happy to use it.

Here's an example:

```css
.testparent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-53%);
}

.test {
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="testparent">
    <div class="test">
      <button>Hello.</button>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu omnium equidem quo, id primis nostro atomorum his. Ad mel facer dicam. Ad vix stet perpetua, ex omnes referrentur vel. Sed te omnes doming, mea ea prima iracundia. Eruditi recteque an cum.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is run in Chrome, it works.

Comment: For modern browsers the prefixes aren't needed anymore.

Comment: Yes, but what other way could I fix the translateY() issue?

Comment: Post a [mcve] to your question please

Comment: Alright, here it is.

Comment: With your example, a negative value for translate moves an element UP not down. Also, your example doesn't necessarily function because for `top: 50%` to work, the containing element, in this case `body` needs a height set.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.